# How do I perform this php loop and multiple mysql queries with just one query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query which gets the earliest date in which race times start being recorded for runners in a race:

```
SELECT
    MIN(races.eventdate)
FROM
    races,
    runners
WHERE
    races.id=runners.raceid AND runners.time_hsecs IS NOT NULL
```

`races` table has a list of races, as well as the tracks they are at.
`runners`table  has the runners in each race and their times.

The query above gets the earliest date in which finish times were being recorded. But what if I wanted to get the earliest date for each trackname? With my limited experience, I would create a loop that goes through each track names and then perform the same query above but isolated just to each track, for example (pseudo code)

```
foreach($trackname_array as $some_name) {

    SELECT
        MIN(races.eventdate)
    FROM
        races,
        runners
    WHERE
        races.id=runners.raceid AND runners.time_hsecs IS NOT NULL
    AND
        races.trackname=$some_name

    // returns earliest eventdate that matches the query for trackname

}
```

But I would like to learn how is something like this done purely in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    MIN(races.eventdate) as eventDate,races.trackname
 FROM
    races,
    runners
WHERE
    races.id=runners.raceid AND runners.time_hsecs IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  races.trackName, date(races.eventdate)
```

If I have understood correctly

Comment: I think you did understand. Your query kind of worked, but not with the grouping of eventdate. The group by trackName was suffice! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the `GROUP BY` syntax:

```
SELECT
    MIN(races.eventdate) as eventDate, races.id AS raceId,races.trackname
 FROM
    races,
    runners
WHERE
    races.id=runners.raceid AND runners.time_hsecs IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY races.id, races.trackName
```

Comment: races.id is already unique though. my apologies if I have not explained it correctly

Comment: Uniqueness does not matter for the GROUP BY statement. For your scenario I think this query will return what you are looking for (or that you have to play around with the GROUP BY a bit based on this example)